# Set background of android activity without using XML file

Tags: android, android-layout, background

I want to develop an application in which I want to set the background image which is in my drawable folder. I want when my activity will run, the back ground will be that image.And also no XML is to be used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without XML file,

Create an `ImageView` and set drawable to it. Now use `setContentView(View view)` of Activity..

Simple...

Dynamically,

//pseudo code only.. Implement in your way..

```
OnCreate()
{
 ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
 imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
 setContentView(imageView);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.yourImage)` method for your layout.Suppose your main layout is `LinearLayout`

```
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lineaLayout);
  ll.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.yourImage); // like this you can set image for your layout
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Simple solution..

Use this in your onCreate() method of Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a handle to the root layout used, then set the background color or drawable on that. The root layout is whatever you called setContentView with.
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

```
// Now get a handle to any View contained  
// within the main layout you are using 
View someView = findViewById(R.id.randomViewInMainLayout); 

// Find the root view 
View root = someView.getRootView() 

// Set the color 
root.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.red);
```